# Where to find information on handshake messsages a new node needs to exchange with a peer?

Tags: network, node-discovery, discovery-protocol

So I am looking to dig further into how new nodes join the ethereum network. I am looking at studying this for both the execution and consensus layer.

Specifically I am interested in knowing:

1. How do new nodes find new peers
2. When new peers are found, I believe some handshake will have to occur? Where can I find the handshake specification?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to study, it is good to start looking at the sources:

here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/eth/protocols/eth

and here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/p2p